# Best practices for using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

I would like to make sure when using SqlCommand that I am using best practices, particularly with regards to security.

Considerations that I am not sure about:

1. Is it ok to manually build the string by appending? If not, how should I do it?
2. What classes should I be looking at using instead?

Comment: The question would be better if you gave us an example of what you are doing, imho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your first question is talking about building SQL by including the *values* directly, that's almost certainly *not* okay. It opens you up to SQL injection attacks, as well as issues with conversions (e.g. having to get the right date/time format).

Instead, you should use a *parameterized query*, and set the values in the parameters. See the docs for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

Out of interest, do you have a particular reason for using SQL directly instead of using one of the many ORMs around? (LLBL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, LINQ to SQL, SubSonic, Massive, SimpleData, Dapper...)

Comment: I would recommend using stored procs every time you can and this is one of those times since you are using Sql Server.

Comment: Using parameters prevents "SQL Injection" attacks!

Comment: @Icarus: Recommendations without justifications are fairly pointless IMO. What's the benefit here?

Comment: @Zachary: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. I've already talked about SQL injection attacks (first paragraph).

Comment: I'm looking to load a large well formatted dataset into a database for analysis in a stat package. I'm using C# and basically want to query to see if certain tables exist or not, then load the data. I was looking at SqlCommand for checking tables existing and then SqlBulkCopy to load the data.

Comment: @mindless.panda: Okay, that makes sense... putting the *table names* in via string concatenation is okay, so long as you either trust the data source or do some really brutal validation (e.g. must be completely A-Za-z).

Comment: @JonSkeet I was thinking even if its a small project I'd like to establish good practice, otherwise when the larger ones come along it usually doesn't happen. I'm using SqlCommand.Parameters right now, is it overkill?

Comment: If it's already in a dataset, create table valued type and then pass that as a parameter to your proc. http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html

Comment: @mindless.panda: No, I don't think it's overkill at all, using parameters. It's a very good way of keeping your code (the SQL) separate from the data (the parameter values).

Comment: @billinkc By dataset I mean just a flat text file usually about 1GB, that I know to be well formatted, not neccesarily a DataSet object of any kind.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: with the information mindless.panda provided initially, I thought using sql procs made more sense since you have several advantages: 1. Protected against sql injection attacks as long as you are not doing sp_executesql inside your proc. 2. You may gain performance since the execution plan will make use of statistics collected on the table to determine the best execution plan. 3. You abstract your logic from the front-end by implementing logic on the proc if needed. If you find a problem with your data/logic you may be able to fix it on the database side... etc, etc.

Comment: @Icarus: On the other hand, if you find you want a different query you *have* to fix it on the database side, in a way which in my experience is typically more of a pain to change on a live system than changing the database access. Prepared statements can also use table statistics for optimization IIRC, and using parameters is just as good at protecting against SQL injection attacks. Note that this doesn't have to be true frontend code - it could well be an internal web service or something similar. I typically wouldn't want a UI talking *directly* to the database anyway.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: "if you find you want a different query you have to fix it on the database side, in a way which in my experience is typically more of a pain to change on a live system than changing the database access.", elaborate on that, please. I don't see how is more painful or very painful than having to do a new release of your app, unless, of course, you are talking about IoC, DI, etc. W/o the complete pic one can only suggest so much...

Comment: @Icarus: My experience is that applying database changes can require rather more "process" getting involved (more talking to DBAs etc) than applying application changes. I also find it less obvious what's going on in the code than seeing SQL directly or - ideally - using an ORM. I also find the development process slower, as typically while you're tweaking the stored proc you *also* need to tweak the client code (e.g. to pass different parameters) so you've got two bits to update instead of one. Ditto adding a new query. (Continued.)

Comment: You only need to *just* change the database if your stored proc already takes all the right parameters, the client is calling it correctly, but the logic is wrong. In my experience changes are more often "Oh, and we also need to filter by X". Stored procs have their place, but I certainly don't think they're the most appropriate approach "every time you can [use them]" as you do.

Comment: @Icarus just to add a voice - Ive used both routes (stored proc and direct sql) successfully, but I agree that direct SQL has many advantages; deployment *is* a biggie, and in particular that awkward time when updaon the farm when you want the data logic and app logic to be correct for all servers at all times. For us, deploying the app tier is trivial.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: "...just change the database if your stored proc already takes all the right parameters, the client is calling it correctly, but the logic is wrong", yes and no, also if you "Oh, and we also need to filter by X" can be done w/o making any code changes as opposed to having to make a code change and subsequent release just for "oh, I also need to filter by X and I forgot". Or what about a bug (typical scenario) because you are parsing data wrong? Most likely you can fix it on the proc. I find MORE productive to write sql statements in one of the many SQL tools... (Continued).

Comment: (SQL Server Mgmt Studio for example), than writing them on the client -you have lots of productivity tools, intellisense, etc-

Comment: @Marc Gravell. Exactly, one has to look at the scenario at hand to determine what works best. Perhaps stored procs are not the panacea, but I prefer them over prepared statements. What if the logic becomes over complicated, you need to join 50 tables and what not? Writing those sql statements in code is not fun at all and hardly more productive than writing them on tools such as Sql Server Mgmt Studio, specially if you use SqlPrompt -Redgate should pay me for this free ad ;)- or things like that, that check for syntax errors and format your sql statements very nicely.

Comment: @Icarus: If I'm joining 50 tables, I think there are bigger issues :) But I'd rather write joins in LINQ anyway, to be honest. My point about the "filter by X" was something like "filter by the date value given by the user" - i.e. introducing another parameter. How would you do that without making code changes?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: in that case you are out of luck ;) But if you went into production and realized that you are returning more data than you should (say for example based on user credentials if using windows auth), you can put that little filter in there w/o anybody knowing. Or for some other reason, whatever it is. There is that possibility and is not miniscule, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Icarus: Sure, that's possible. But either way you'd be modifying one tier. Where I have a problem is with *every* new query requiring at least *two* tiers of change.

Comment: @Joh Skeet. Understandable, but if you are already changing the front-end tier, what's the big deal about changing the other tier as  well Vs being able to possibly address many issues transparently by changing only one tier that requires no downtime and is -almost (wishful thinking)- truly painless?

Comment: @Icarus: Truly painless? You haven't dealt with the DBAs I have ;) (It takes longer to do development changing two things at a time too, in my experience.) I think we'll have to agree to differ...

Comment: Hahaha, We agree on that! Regards.

Comment: @Icarus - we *do* write our TSQL in SSMS, and our logging/profiling layer happily spits it back to use with suitable fake `declare @someParam int = 12` etc for review

Answer (score 2):

I would say use of parameters is one of the most important aspects for security. This will prevent SQL Injection into your database. The following SQLCommand is an example of how I would construct one (in VB.NET, apologies - no C# knowledge - yet ;))

```
Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("sp_StoredProcedure", Conn)
cmd.commandType = commandtypes.storedprocedure
cmd.parameters.add("@ID",sqldbtype.int).value = myID
cmd.executenonquery
```

And an example of an inline SqlCommand:

```
Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Message FROM [Table] WHERE ID=@ID", Conn)
cmd.commandType = commandtypes.storedprocedure
cmd.parameters.add("@ID",sqldbtype.int).value = myID
cmd.executenonquery
```

Answer (score 2):

My advice: be lazy. Writing voluminous code is a good way to make brain-dead errors (wrong data type, null checks, missing Dispose(), etc), and it has **zero** performance advantage over many of the helper tools.

Personally, I'm a big fan of dapper (but I'm somewhat biased), which makes things easy:

```
int customerId = ...
var orders = connection.Query<Order>(
    @"select * from Customers where CustomerId = @customerId",
    new { customerId });
```

Which will do parameterisation and materialisation for you without pain, and stupidly fast.

For other scenarios, and in particular when you want to use OO techniques to update the system, an ORM such as EF or L2S will save you work while (and giving you better type-checking via LINQ).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best solution

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strCn);
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from xxxx", cn))
            {
                cn.Open();

                //do something

                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            cn.Close();
            throw exception;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think this is the best solution?

Comment: Automatically releases the resources and automatically closing the connection provided. Why do you thinks it's not?

Answer (score 0):

Depending, when I do POC or personnal small projects I normally build my strings manually but when im in a project for work we have a template for DB usage and connection that I must use and can't reveal here obviously.

But I think it's ok to manually build for basic operations in small project or POC.

- Edit : Like Jon said though you should always use somehting like SqlCommand.Parameters when building your own command. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about security, I recommend create your queries as Stored Procedures inside the SQL Server Database instead (to prevent worrying about SQL injection), and then from the front end code, just generate a SQL Stored Procedure, add the parameters, and do it that way.

[This](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx) article should help you out with setting this up.

Comment: Why not just use parameterized queries instead, which still avoid SQL injection attacks?

Comment: Well it's more a preference thing. I prefer to be able to go and look at all my stored procs and know that that's where all my Database operations are happening =/

Comment: That's reasonable - but it does make it rather a pain to create new queries etc, in my experience. If every new way of querying the database requires a new stored proc to get rolled out, there's a lot of admin involved :(

Comment: Stored procs don't _prevent_ SQL injection attacks.  There's nothing preventing the SP author from using `sp_executesql` way too liberally and opening up a hole there.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the practice of applying the least privileges to database connections by communicating with the database through stored procedures.

Store Procs

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
  SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter("LoginStoredProcedure", connection);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@au_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@au_id"].Value = SSN.Text;
  myCommand.Fill(userDataset);
}
```

- The credentials for the connection string to the database:
  A. Integrated Security for corporate/intranet
  B. Keep it encrypted in the registry or a file in Hosting Providers.
- Always be on the lookout for hackers trying to upload cross scripting into your forms.
- Always check the input for SQL injection.